# Google App Engine Flexible not finding sklearn

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scikit-learn, requirements.txt

So I'm trying to upload my app to `Google App Engine Flexible` with `Python 3.6` and I have the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
```

I've gone through previous questions:

[error installing scikit-learn python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046646/error-installing-scikit-learn-python3)

[Install custom sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457225/install-custom-sklearn)

[trouble importing skllearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582896/trouble-importing-skllearn)

[sklearn ImportError: No module named _check_build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062524/sklearn-importerror-no-module-named-check-build)

And I haven't had any luck.

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-storage==1.8.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
PyMySQL==0.8.0
numpy
scipy
sklearn
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `sklearn` try `scikit-learn` on the `requirements.txt`. [Installing scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)